# Using Prototype.js with C3.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, c3.js

I have an old web project that uses prototype.js and I'm trying to add charting to it using C3.

Unfortunately there's an error since prototype seems to add a bunch of methods to arrays and this specific method in c3.js checkValueInTargets uses Object.keys which grabs all the random methods in the array and then throws an error.

Is there a way to "hide" my charting code from prototype or a way to use the default JS arrays?

I can't remove or upgrade prototype unfortunately.

Thanks

sample project:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
        }
        // or
        //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3DW/269/

Comment: you have linked to version 1.6.1, are you able to upgrade to 1.7.2 released April 2014?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't; it's an existing project and upgrading is beyond the scope of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: the error is with `Object.keys` so you might be able to copy that method and revert the change after prototype loads? or there might be something that can be done inside the C3.js file to make the `checkValueInTargets()` method handle the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to fix it would be to move the prototype script loading to after c3.js chart initialization call.

```
    ...
    <link href="lib/c3.js/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div id="chart"></div>
    ...
    <script src="lib/d3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="lib/c3.js/c3.js"></script>
    <script>
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
                ],
                type: 'bar'
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                }
                // or
                //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script src="lib/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
    <!-- prototype code --->
</body>
```

---

If this is not possible, you could have a script block to store a reference to the native Object.keys and swap it out and back again when calling the C3 code, like so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>C3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        var originalKeys = Object.keys;
    </script>
    <script src="lib/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script src="lib/d3/d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="lib/c3.js/c3.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/c3.js/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        var prototypeKeys = Object.keys;
        Object.keys = originalKeys;
        var chart = c3.generate({
            data: {
                columns: [
                    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                    ['data2', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50]
                ],
                type: 'bar'
            },
            bar: {
                width: {
                    ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
                }
                // or
                //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
            }
        });
        Object.keys = prototypeKeys;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Luckily tooltips don't cause any problems

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/td433xt1/

Comment: Works very good for a chart with axes. However prototype.js still breaks something when trying to make a pie chart. Only the legend appears. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?